# What remains in C if I exclude libraries and compiler extensions?

Tags: c, compilation, use-case

Imagine a situation where you can't or don't want to use any of the libraries provided by the compiler as "standard", nor any external library. You can't use even the compiler extensions (such as [gcc extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html)).

What is the remaining part you get if you strip C language of all the things a lot of people use as a matter of course?

In such a way, probably a list of every callable function supported by any big C compiler (not only ANSI C) out-of-box would be satisfying as as answer as it'd at least approximately show the use-case of the language.

First I thought about `sizeof()` and `printf()` (those were already clarified in the comments - operator + `stdio`), so... what remains? [In-line assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm) seem like an extension too, so that pretty much strips even the option to *use* assembly with C if I'm right.

Probably in the matter of code it'd be easier to understand. Imagine a code compiled with only e.g. `gcc main.c` (output flag permitted) that has no `#include`, nor `extern`.

```
int main() {
    // replace_me
    return 0;
}
```

What can I call to actually do something else than "boring" type math and casting from type to type?

Note that `switch`, `goto`, `if`, loops and other constructs that do nothing and only allow repeating a piece of code aren't the thing I'm looking for (if it isn't obvious).

---

(Hopefully the edit clarified wtf I'm actually asking, but Matteo's answer pretty much did it.)

Comment: `sizeof` is actually a language keyword, not a function, so it's "built in."

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I reread your question three times.

Comment: You need to look up in your compiler documentation.  All the "Builtins" stuff here, looks like a good start https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C -Extensions.html. However -  if you also run the code on bare metal, you might be able to access all the registers and peripherals on your platform/CPU directly, and could fly a quadcopter without using any standard or 3. party header files - if that was your platform.

Comment: `sizeof` is built in. `printf` is from `stdio.h`. C actually doesn't define very much - it's big thing (back in the day) was that everything was done by a function rather than being built in to the language. Contrast that with, say, PL/I or Modula-2 or Ada or Fortran or ALGOL.

Comment: I don't get the question. In MSVC `replace_me;` generates "error C2065: 'replace_me': undeclared identifier". If you want to know what is in the library, please refer to its documentation. For example [here is a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2.aspx) of MSVC library functions.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie wrote C to be a small language with very simple syntax and constructs for a very good reason. C would not be as flexible and pervasive if it wasn't written this way, I don't think. I would quote K&R C, but I can't find my copy of the book.

Comment: @DeiDei As said above, I'm trying to find a use-case for raw C code without any libraries used. If I can e.g. make my own libraries from it and slowly extend an empty main() to something useful.

Comment: The question is nuts. First you ask where you can get a list of library functions, but you go on to say you don't want to use them.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure, are you a troll? That is a placeholder for whatever useful I can do with raw C.

Comment: What are *"assembly strings"*?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David Yes, but I don't believe he already had libs for it before he wrote the lang itself, so it has to have some functions (most likely depending on compiler) thar can move me further a step by step to more complicated stuff such as drivers or so.

Comment: @Clifford https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm ok, I got it wrong, those aren't strings, but it's using assembly. Apparently it's an extension only, so it isn't useful for the question either. :/

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr All of the libraries in C are written in C so you can implement all of it yourself if you want. I am not sure how this works, but Brain Kernighan said it an interview with the Computerphile people that the original C language was itself written in C (I may have misunderstood, though).

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr : The more ususl term is "in-line assembly".  In-line assembly syntax varies across compilers, and of course the assembly mnemonics, instruction and register sets differ across architectures.  The embedding of in-line assembly in literal strings is not universal, and was originally peculiar to gcc as far as I know.

Comment: @Clifford Oh? Good to know even its inplementation can be unstable if we leave the architecture out.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David : true, although C being written in C is not the same thing as C libraries being written in C.  The library and the language are separate entities. "Compiler bootstrapping" is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers) for example.  If a compiler can generate any program and a compiler is a program, then a compiler can be used to write a compiler.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the link! I've been very curious about how that works!

Comment: I'll try to reformulate the question to hm... more "sane" bunch of characters tomorrow as I'm only on a phone right now (and it's 1am here). Feel free to reformulate it if you want to though, I'm still +/- tapping in the dark when the topic is about such a low-level thing.

Comment: `sizeof` and `alignof` are _operators_ like `+`, `&` etc. As such they are also keywords, but that's a syntax matter, not about grammar. And it is not clear what your problem is. If you want to know what valid C is, read the standard.

Comment: @Olaf I hope I clarified it now. If you read the accepted answer, that's the thing I asked. Unfortunately I probably can't formulate it properly.

Comment: Just to make that clear: If you cannot use the **mandatory** headers even a freestanding implementation is required to provide, you do **not** use C.  And yes, "assembly blocks" are an extension, too. But I still don't see your point, reading the standard would be a good start.

Comment: @Olaf My point is to see what is C as a bare language for. I come from high-level background first, and although I've played with C and C++ for a while, it always bothers me if I don't know what are the bare lang's capabilities first, because libraries are just additional stuff built on the core.

Comment: Not sure what you conder "high level language". It is commonly accepted that C very well is a high level language. It just does not support higher abstractions from the language itself (although one obviously can implement any abstraction in it, too, of course).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137496/discussion-between-keyweeusr-and-olaf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove all libraries essentially you have something similar to a *freestanding* implementation of C (which still has to provide some libraries - say, string.h, but that's nothing you couldn't easily implement yourself in portable C), and that's what normally you start with when programming microcontrollers and other computers that don't have a ready-made operating system - and what operating system writers in general use when they compile their operating systems.

There you typically have two ways of doing stuff besides "raw" computation:

- assembly blocks (where you can do literally anything the underlying machine can do);
- memory mapped IO (you set a `volatile` pointer to some hardware dependent location and read/write from it; that affects hardware stuff).

That's really all you need to build anything - and after all, it all boils down to that stuff anyway, the C library of a regular hosted implementation is normally written in C itself, with some assembly used either for speed or to communicate with the operating system<sup>1</sup> (typically the syscalls are invoked through some kind of interrupt).

Again, it's nothing you couldn't implement yourself. But the point of having a standard library is both to avoid to continuously reinvent the wheel, and to have a set of *portable* functions that spare you to have to rewrite everything knowing the details of each target platform.

---

1. And mainstream operating systems, in turn, are generally written in a mix or C and assembly as well.

Comment: Ok, I believe the pointers are the real magic of C (kind of expected that), but what do you mean by read/write of that? Just changing the values of certain places in memory? Is that the way how the rest of the first libraries were "born"?

Comment: It depends from how the underlying hardware works. On some processors to do IO you have to use special assembly instructions; on others, some memory locations are "magic" and, when reading/writing them, you are not acting on "regular" memory, but on hardware peripherals (on AVRs, for example, a few memory locations are mapped straight to the status of some pins on the IC; on the IBM PC some memory locations were mapped straight to the video card framebuffer). But that's just a possibility, generally some work has to be done in asm blocks.

Comment: Do you by assembly blocks mean a compiler extension I mentioned in the comments under my question, or is there a way to work with assembly directly without it, just bare gcc main.c?

Comment: Every compiler has its way to specify assembly blocks; of course it's not going to be standard (although the `asm` keyword is listed as a "common extension" in the C standard), given that assembly itself is platform specific. I don't get what you mean with "bare gcc main.c", `asm` blocks, despite being implementation specific, are generally a builtin, so there's nothing particular to do to activate them.

Comment: I thought so. Perfect then, so that leaves us with the memory accessing. I'm not sure if that is an easy thing to explain, but if you by any chance happen to know of an example of such manipulation that's used as a more advanced library (not just another memory manipulation directly), please let me know. I'd like to see an actual thing, because now I kind of think of C like a chicken&egg problem, hehe.

Comment: `string.h` is **not** required for a freestanding implementation. The headers which have to be provided by **any** implementation are listed in the standard. These are basically those which provide implementation-details, and allow to write portable code.

Answer (score 3):

C has no "built-in" functions as such. A compiler implementation may include "[intrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx)" functions that are implemented directly by the compiler without provision of an external library, although a prototype declaration is still required for intrinsics, so you would still normally include a header file for such declarations.

C is a systems-level language with a minimal run-time and start-up requirement.  Because it can directly access memory and memory mapped I/O there is very little that it cannot do (and what it cannot do is what you use assembly, in-line assembly or intrinsics for).  For example, much of the library code you are wondering what you can do without is written in C.  When running in an OS environment however (using C as an application-level rather then system-level language), you cannot practically use C in that manner - the OS has control over such things as I/O and memory-management and in modern systems will normally prevent unmediated access to such resources.  Of course that OS itself is likely to largely written in C (and/or C++).

In a standalone of bare-metal environment with no OS, C is often used very early in the bootstrap process initialising hardware and establishing an application execution environment.  In fact on ARM Cortex-M processors it is possible to boot directly into C code from reset, since the hardware loads an initial stack-pointer and start address from the vector table on start-up; this being enough to run C code that does not rely on library or static data initialisation - such initialisation can however be written in C before calling `main()`.

Note that `sizeof` is not a function, it is an [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

Comment: I didn't know about intrinsic directly, but I believe it's the most similar to the scripting languages-like built ins, such as for python's https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html + even for the sizeof, I've seen it only with the brackets, so I kind of thought it's a function. My bad.

Comment: Python (being a higher-level interpreted language) built-ins are not really comparable with intrinsics.  In a C compiler intrinsics are generally used to generate architecture specific code that cannot be implemented in C and would otherwise require assembly (usually because it needs core register access or to support i/o mapped (rather then memory-mapped) access necessary on some architectures, or to generate architecture specific code that the compiler is better able to optimise -  in-line assembler relies on the expertise of the author, and the compiler will not second-guess it.

Comment: Hm, so compiler-_only_ builtins, not C. Yep, that makes it a little bit different thing, but still it's probably the closest thing to e.g. python built-ins if the basic C "keywords" (types, operators, ...) are left off and those aren't really built-ins in that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really understand the situation.

You don't need a header to call a function in C. You can call with unchecked parameters - a bad idea and an obsolete feature, but still supported. And if a compiler links a library by default instead of only when you explicitly tell it to, that's only a little switch within the compiler to "link libc". Notoriously Unix compilers need to be told to link the math library, it wasn't linked by default because some very early programs didn't use floating point.

To be fair, some standard library functions like memcpy tend to be special-cased these days as they lend themselves to inlining and optimisation.

The standard library is documented and is usually available, though in effect deprecated by Microsoft for security reasons. You can write pretty much any function quite easily with only stdlib functions, what you can't do is fancy IO.

Comment: To be fair, I believe my question is badly formulared. I don't want to use libs. I'm just trying to understand what can I do with C if I don't have an access to any of that stuff, but Matteo Italia described it probably the best.